# Zend Framework: Get whole out output in postDispath while using Layout

Tags: zend-framework, layout, response

I have a layout loader plugin which looks like this:

```
class Controller_Action_Helper_LayoutLoader extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $config = Zend_Registry::get("config");

        $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();

        if (isset($config->$module->resources->layout->layout) && !$this->getRequest()->format)
        {
            $layoutScript = $config->$module->resources->layout->layout;
            $this->getActionController()->getHelper('layout')->setLayout($layoutScript);
        }
    }
}
```

In a controller plugin I then want to get the whole of the response like so

```
$this->getResponse()->getBody()
```

This however only returns the output from the action, not the output from the layout too.

How can I get the whole output, layout and action together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `Zend_Layout` operates at `postDispatch()` with a high stack index. So, to get the content, you might need to do your access later, at `dispatchLoopShutdown()`.