# Smarty Template Engine and Gzip encoding

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding, gzip, smarty

I've a bit problem with smarty, Zend and gzip encoding, I extends the smarty class

```
//This method i call in one front controller plugin
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Encoding' , 'gzip');

View extends Zend_View_Abstract implements Zend_View_Interface {

   public $_smarty;

   public function __construct(){

      $this->_smarty = new Smarty();
      //Hire i have some smarty options paths and etc.
      //------------------
      //I register this object to smarty template
      $this->_smarty->registerObject('Smarty', $this);

      //You can see this pulugin at this address
      //http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=GZipPlugin
      $this->_smarty->loadFilter('output', 'gzip');

   }


   public function Fetch($tpl){
      retutn $this->_smarty->fetch($tpl);
   }

   //Zend call this method after loaded controller and display active controller tpl
   public function Render($tpl){
      retutn $this->_smarty->display($tpl);
   }

   public function Header($params, &$smarty){
      $this->_smarty->display('header.tpl');
   }


}
```

Ok...
in my index.tpl i call the function {Site->header}
and my browser chrome throw the error:

```
Server error.

The website encountered an error while retrieving http://site.dev. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

i've tried to load with fetch like:

```
echo $this->_smarty->fetch('header.tpl');
```

but i have the same error, when i remove the out put fillter site is running.

If anyone can help me I would been greatly appreciate it.
Sorry if my english is not very good.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Smarty. PHP is already a template language and Zend_View gives you a nice way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with mfonda, don't use Smarty.

I use use this plugin class to Gzip my entire body response when needed:

```
class Lib_Controller_Plugin_Gzip extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
    {
        $content = $this->getResponse()->getBody();

        $content = preg_replace(
                    array('/(\x20{2,})/',   '/\t/', '/\n\r/'),
                    array(' ',      ' ',    ' '),
                    $content
                );

        if (@strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') === FALSE) 
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($content);
        else 
        {
            header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(gzencode($content, 9));
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of `dispatchLoopShutdown` because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581271/zend-framework-get-whole-out-output-in-postdispath-while-using-layout).

The class was adapted from [this post](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Use-ob-gzhandler-with-ZF-td668519.html) I found by using Google

Comment: Ok, i removed the smarty from my system.